# Finding permutations off given action

Tags: permutations, cryptography

Let $\mathfrak{A}=\{A,\dots,Z\}$ and $\pi_i$ be involutions on $\mathfrak{A}$ without fixed points, $i=1,2,3$. Given are all triples $\pi_1(a)\pi_2(a)\pi_3(a)$ for $a\in\mathfrak{A}$:

> APN BOY CCQ DTT ESF FXM GQE HEO IHR JRB KLU LZG MYJ
>
> NJI OFA PAV QGC RWW SMK TKX UBH VVP WIZ XDL YND ZUS

Task: Find $\pi_1,\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$.

---

What I've got so far:

1) We have $\pi_i\pi_j(a_j)=a_i$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ since $\pi_i^2=\text{id}_\mathfrak{A}$. With this I was able to find all $\pi_i\pi_j$. I will not list them here as this takes up too much time and space.

2) My goal now is to find either one of the $\pi_i$'s since knowing one implies knowing the others.

3) If $a$  is a fixed point of $\pi_i\pi_j$, then $\pi_j(a)$ is a also a fixed point of $\pi_i\pi_j$ and $(a,\pi_j(a))$ is a cycle of $\pi_j$.

4) Since $\pi_1\pi_2$ has fixed points C and V and $\pi_2$ doesn't have fixed points we can conclude $\pi_2(C)=V$ and $\pi_2(V)=C$. Simmilar considering $\pi_3\pi_2$ we can obtain $\pi_2(T)=W$ and $\pi_2(W)=T$.

So in total $\pi_2=(CV)(TW)\cdots$ is what I have. Is there a smart way to get more?

Comment: What are $a_1, a_2, a_3$? I assume the triples are in some random order (sorted on the first, so it seems)?

Comment: Yes, $a_1=\pi_1(a)$ and so on. I managed to solve it by now. It is actually quite easy if you take the Information of $\pi_2(W)=T$ and use it for the block DTT to obtain $\pi_1(W)=D$ and $\pi_3(W)=T$, etc.

Comment: $a_1 =\pi_1(A)$ you mean?

Comment: No, $a_1=\pi(a), a_2=\pi_2(a), a_3=\pi_3(a)$ for any $a\in\mathfrak A$ as I wrote.

Comment: Then how does 1) hold?

Comment: We have $\pi_1(a)=a_1$ and $\pi_2(a)=a_2$, so $\pi_1 (a_1)=a=\pi_2(a_2)$ and therefore $\pi_2\pi_1(a_1)=a_2$ and so on.

Comment: OK I see. How do you determine all $\pi_i\pi_j$ then?

Comment: For example we have $\pi_1\pi_2(a_2)=a_1$ so we know that $\pi_1\pi_2$ just maps the 2nd to the 1st digit of the given 3 blocks. From the first block we can observe $\pi_1\pi_2(P)=A$, from the second block $\pi_1\pi_2(O)=B$, etc.